# change language of WiXUI with MSBuild

Tags: xml, msbuild, wix, windows-installer

I have a installer to deploy my application.
Actually, i dont use Visual Studio or Light.exe command, I was using the MSBuild command.
I would change the langage (english to german by example) of my WiXUI in wxs or wixproj files.
I read the documentation and i don't find if an element exists for this because i don't use the command light directly.

By example, I found a trick to add WixUIExtension into my wixproj file without the light command:

```
<Project>
...
 <ItemGroup>
  <WixExtension Include="WixUIExtension" />
  <Compile ...../>
  ...
 </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Do you have solution for my case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `PropertyGroup` and add the `Cultures` to it, this way:

```
<Project ...>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <Cultures>en-US;es-MX;pt-BR</Cultures>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

You can add the `Cultures` under the `WixExtension` but in my tests it didn't produce the desired results.